# Query distinct values Django with MySql and keep foreign key relation

Tags: mysql, django

I have two tables in a MySQL database. One table with distinct vessels and one table with locations of that vessels with a foreign key relation (parents: vessels, children: locations). Now I want to show in a template al the distinct vessels from the table with the locations. Unfortunatally the distinct does not work with MySQL and if I use the values() then I lose the foreign key relation. How can I fix this?

Comment: Unclear. Show source data and desired result for it.

Comment: Why not query the vessels (with a `.prefetch_related(..)` to the `Location` objects).